# Autocomplete functionality to search through json object by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

Suppose I have the following json object, containing information about a set of people.

```
data=[{id:2, fname:"bob", lname:"roberts", common_name:null, email:"sideshowbob@email.com", telephone:"555-555-5555", street:"333 Street St", city:"Salt Lake City", state:"UT", country:null, zip:"99999", dynamid:null, notes:null, director:false, contractor:false, contractor_need_agreement:false, shareholder:false, shares_held:0, company_id:1, created_at:"2016-02-23T10:15:09.339Z", updated_at:"2016-02-23T10:15:09.339Z", officer:false, snapshot:null, sign_term_voting:false, drag_liquidation_approval:false, rofr_consenter:false, investor_councel:false, ir_insured:false, issuer_signing_officer:false, issuer_registered_agent:false, issuer_councel:false, rep_lead_investor:false, rep_investor:false, rep_founder:false}, 
      {id:1, fname:"John", lname:"Smith", common_name:null, email:"john.smith@email.com", telephone:"555-555-5555", street:"333 Street St", city:"Salt Lake City", state:"UT", country:null, zip:"99999", dynamid:null, notes:null, director:false, contractor:false, contractor_need_agreement:false, shareholder:false, shares_held:0, company_id:1, created_at:"2016-02-23T10:15:09.327Z", updated_at:"2016-02-23T10:15:09.327Z", officer:false, snapshot:null, sign_term_voting:false, drag_liquidation_approval:false, rofr_consenter:false, investor_councel:false, ir_insured:false, issuer_signing_officer:false, issuer_registered_agent:false, issuer_councel:false, rep_lead_investor:false, rep_investor:false, rep_founder:false}]
```

Now I would like to implement some sort of auto-complete functionality in a text box that searches through each person's name (That is `fname+" "+lname`) looking for a match.  Upon finding the match it either returns the person for whom it found a match or the id of that person.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting started on this.  I figure I could write it out longhand where I use `keyup` to trigger a loop through the object, display those names matching the string and return the corresponding index upon clicking on one of them, but that seems like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Is there an efficient/best practice way to pull of this sort of functionality?

Comment: you can try JqueryUI autocomplete feature...

Comment: you can keep  all fname+" "+lname in an array  and provide it as source for auto-complete functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this typeahead.js demo [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/):

complete code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/refan/a62vuceu/1/):

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    matches = [];

    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      var fullname = str.fname + " " + str.lname
            console.log(fullname);

      if (substrRegex.test(fullname)) {
        matches.push(fullname);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response and the fiddle.  I'd be interested in ultimately getting other attributes out of the autocomplete when I select the value (namely the id from the object).  How might I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, Could you give an example

Comment: if you want to reach the id of selected person: https://jsfiddle.net/refan/a62vuceu/4/

Comment: Hi thanks for the update.  Sorry I didn't reply sooner.  I'll take a closer look at this when I get a sec but it looks like what I'm after.  I'll be sure to credit your answer once I try it.

Comment: Your latest fiddle was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much.